# Vista Style DropDownMenu with TrackBar

Tags: c#, vb.net, custom-controls, drop-down-menu

In Windows Vista/7's windows explorer, the Icon Size selector has got a [track bar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.aspx) in the [DropDownMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownmenu.aspx) (see Fig. 1)

[image: Vista DropDownMenu with TrackBar]
*Fig. 1: DropDownMenu with TrackBar in Windows Vista*

Does anyone know where I can get a similar UserControl or show me how to replicate it in .NET?

**NOTE:** If anyone's wondering where the image came from, I captured it from Windows Vista's Windows Explorer when I clicked on the Views Button.

**Edit**
I realised that Trilian 5 beta also has something similar. I'll try to get a screenshot of it soon enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an article at CodeProject. It allows such a menu. This will be of assistance to you.

WPF Slider Menu 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Slider_Menu.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I'd have loved to see a WinForms version too. But hey, Vista and Win7 pushed WPF so it's just logical that the first replication was also done in WPF.